# Autoset High DPI Settings

Tags: vb.net, compatibility, highdpi

My program coded in VB.NET (build using .net framework 3.5) does not display properly if display scaling is > 100%. To fix this I go to exe properties and set compatibility - override high DPI settings - system.

Can this be set automatically or via command line? Otherwise it has to be done manually using properties window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e